# How to call a function in the main block of code when a prototype is declared

Tags: c++

I am working on a code for class that involves performing numerical integration with the trapezoidal rule and discrete data points. Part of the instructions says to call on the function with the prototype:

```
double trapInt(const double xvals[], const double yvals[], int nElements);
```

I have already declared the prototype before the "int main" portion of the code but I do not fully understand the exact steps to calling the function.

Note: The code involves using one-dimensional arrays. I also have a PDF of the assignment if seeing that would help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ifstream>


using namespace std;

double trapInt(const double xvals[], const double yvals[], int nElements);


int main()
{
const int MAX_SIZE = 101;
double xData[MAX_SIZE];
double yData[MAX_SIZE];

ifstream infile("trapezoidData.txt");
if(infile.fail())
  {
    for(int a=0; a<MAX_SIZE; ++a)
    {
      infile >> xData[a] >> yData[a];
      cout << xData[a] << '\t' << yData[a] << endl;
  }

}
else
{
  cout << "Could not open infile." << endl;
}

cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `fail` check is reversed. You are trying to read when opening the file fails, and print an error message when it succeeds.

Comment: Calling the function would be as simple as `double result = trapInt(xData, yData, MAX_SIZE);`

Comment: The prototype declaration seems to be fairly basic. Two `const double` arrays, which are really decayed pointers, and an `int` parameter. What exactly you don't understand about "the exact steps"? You call it like any other function that takes the same parameters.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If i were to simply add an exclamation point in front of "infile" in the line "if(infile.fail())" would that fix the issue of my fail check being reversed?

Comment: @AstroNOT98 Have you tried it, and did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a function is very simple. All you do is give the name of the function and put the parameters similarly to how declare the prototype:

```
main () {
    // implementation...
    trapInt(xvals, yvals, nElements);
    // more implementation...
}
```

Keep in mind though, just adding this line (or a similar one) to your main function will fail to compile without the implementation:

```
double trapInt(const double xvals[], const double yvals[], int nElements) {
    // implementation of the function...
}
```

**Edit:** I originally wanted to leave the calling of the function as an exercise for you, but in the event that you're really in the dark, I'll give you an example:

> trapInt(xData, yData, MAX_SIZE);

Just add that line to your `main()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know my question was rather broad but you seem to have understood what i was asking. However, your answer has left me with another question. Does the line without the declarations (along with the other "instructions" for the function) go inside the line with the declarations, like i have below?

Comment: double trapInt(const double xvals[], const double yvals[], int nElements) {
                                                                          
            trapInt(xvals, yvals, nElements);
}

Comment: Never mind. I understand how to do it now. Thank you again!

Comment: What you are describing is called [Recursion](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/). It's a rather advanced topic for your level, though, but it has it's uses. Probably not what you need, though.